# Steps to get Mono working on Ubuntu like SharpDevelop on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mono-framework

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to try Mono on Ubuntu. I'm having problem with installations like WHAT to install, WHERE to find them, WHICH has to be installed first and HOW to install them. I prefer ".deb" packages since it's easy to use, but I can't find any. Also, I want to install Mono offline.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mono on Ubuntu

Apparently current Ubuntu (11.04?) included mono runtime support so you probably just need monodevelop.

### Packages for Ubuntu 10.4

See http://monodevelop.com/download and click on the Ubuntu icon.

### Compiling from source

There are instructions for Ubuntu 9.04 at http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Building_MonoDevelop_on_Ubuntu 
which might form the basis for building on a later version.

Alternatively, find the latest version and replace 0.16 in the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel build-essential mono-gmcs libmono-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtksourceview2.0-cil libgecko2.0-cil monodoc libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil libmono-cairo2.0-cil gettext

wget http://go-mono.com/sources/monodevelop/monodevelop-0.16.tar.bz2

bunzip2 monodevelop-0.16.tar.bz2

tar xvf monodevelop-0.16.tar

cd monodevelop-0.16

./configure –prefix=`pkg-config –variable=prefix mono`

make

sudo make install
```

-- from [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-monodevelop-from-source-on-ubuntu/)

See also [Ruski's blog](http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx)

It all looks a bit of a mess to me - good luck.

Comment: How if I'm going to install it from a directory? I mean, I'll download source using Windows, then I'll transfer it to my Ubuntu machine. I'm having problem with internet connectivity on Ubuntu so I need use Windows.

Comment: @domanokz: Download source "tarballs", then follow http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Building_MonoDevelop#Building_from_Tarballs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04 it's very easy: Just search for "mono" under "More Apps".

You will see an icon for Mono Develop. Click on it, it will take you to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Ubuntu you should first check aptitude for the simplest installation of Mono and MonoDevelop. Alternatively you can download the source and compile.